# Change button label color Sencha

Tags: html, css, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

How to change the color of buttonLabel in Sencha?
Now it appears as Black, so how to change it
my code:

```
xtype: 'button',
ui: 'plain',
text:'SAVED SEARCHES',
centered:true,
iconCls: 'search',
iconAlign:'center',
height:'100%',              
width:'18%',
left:'29.68%',
cls: 'x-iconalign-top',
labelCls:"font-size: 100%;"
```

Comment: tried it but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried with attributes and i found the solution. i set `labelCls` a custom css class that i have added it to `app.css` file.

Here is the class that i have added to app.css:

```
.customCls
{

color:red;
font-size: 100%;
}
```

And in the js file i set:

```
labelCls:"customCls"
```